# Is a Composite UNIQUE Constraint On an Already UNIQUE Column Redundant?

Tags: database-design, index, index-tuning, unique-constraint

I'd just like to clarify something pretty simple regarding single and composite `UNIQUE` constraints that I can't find a clear answer to.

Assume I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ...
)
```

Would it be safe to say that adding the following constraint:

```sql
UNIQUE(customer_id, name)
```

would be redundant and offer no benefit under any circumstance? In other words, is it useless to create a composite `UNIQUE` constraint that includes a column which is already `UNIQUE`?

This appears to make logical sense, but as I stated, I couldn't find an answer confirming it.

Comment: Seems so, although it could help in DBMSs which do not offer `INCLUDE` on indexes. Out of curiosity, why is there both `id` and `customer_id` if they are both unique? Shouldn't they be the same column?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! `UNIQUE(name)` should do it - `id` is just a surrogate!

Comment: Thanks guys! @Charlieface This is just a really simple example I based off my situation (I'm pulling from multiple sources where the same entities are represented by different IDs)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your example is valid,above constraint is not redundant.

`customer_id` is unique on its own way.

But as per business requirement `customerid+name` should also be unique.

Say as per biz req. `Customer_id` is in specific format or it source is some other system.

`ID` is auto increment and it is use by database internally. So `id` and `customer_id`  both will be need and both there purpose and functionality are different.

As per biz req. `customer_id+name`(some  code) should be unique, and you explicitly define it unique as you do not want to violate biz rule.

So given constraint is not redundant.

`Constraint` has its own demerit i.e. `constraint` is evaluated each when there will be DML operation on table.

So please come with exact table and requirement, so that we can discuss if both constraint is require or how to achieve same thing with single constraint.

Comment: perhaps I should've specified my definition of redundant - I could care less about "business rules" as you put it if the only benefit obtained is purely semantic, and has no effect on the actual constraint and/or indexing (not to mention the potential downsides regarding memory / disk space of unnecessary indexes). My question is purely in regards to performance and memory / disk footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about satisfying a query like this?

```
select col1, col2, col3 from person where customer_id = 785
```

If `customer_id` is the leading component in two indexes, the query optimizer will have a choice as to which one to use. My guess is that it would probably pick the index which has the lowest number of physical pages.

If the query was:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from person where customer_id between 1000000 and 3000000 order by name
```

I think it would probably pick the second one. HTH